# Accessing object property from http call in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, http, angular6

I have an angular application that has a service that calls an api. I Am getting a response that is an Object and I am trying to access a property in that Object but I am not sure how to?

```
0:
attributionText: "from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"
citations: []
exampleUses: []
labels: []
partOfSpeech: "prefix"
relatedWords: []
score: 0
sequence: "0"
sourceDictionary: "ahd-legacy"
text: "Variant of pleo-."
textProns: []
word: "Brylee"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array
```

I am trying to access the 'text' property but I'm not sure how to access this?

**random-word-service.ts**

The methods in my service is defined as :

```
getRandomWord() {
return this.http.get(this.singleWordUrl + this.apiKey)
```

}

```
getSingleWord(word: string) {
    return this.http.get
    (this.wordDefinitionUrl1 + word + this.wordDefinitionUrl2 + this.apiKey)
  }
```

**random-word.ts**

```
export interface RandomWord {
  id: number;
  word: string;
}
```

**word-definition.ts**

```
export interface WordDefinition {
  attributionText: string;
  attributionUrl: string;
  citations: string;
  word: string;
  partOfSpeech: string;
  sequence: string;
  text: string;
  score: number;
}
```

**app-component.ts**

```
callWordService() {
    this.randomWordService.getRandomWord()
      .subscribe((data: RandomWord) => {
        this.randomWord = data;
       console.log(this.randomWord.word)

        if(data) {
          this.randomWordService.getSingleWord(this.randomWord.word)
            .subscribe((data: WordDefinition) => {
            this.defintion = data;
              console.log(this.defintion)
            })
        }
      });
  }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

[JSON Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUYXJ.jpg)

Comment: Once you got the response in subscribe callback you can access your text on the top of the response object like console.log(data.text). I hope data is a single object. else you have to iterate

Comment: When i do `.subscribe((data: WordDefinition) => {
            this.defintion = data;
            console.log(this.defintion.text);
            })
` I am getting 'undefined'. Is this because the object is not available yet?

Comment: Yes in the second subscribe callback

Comment: What would be the best way to ensure that the object is available>

Comment: are you saying you are getting .text is undefined in subscribe callback? I saw your comment in @alokstar answer

Comment: you can check if(data){ if(data.hasOwnProperty("text"){ } } . But I think your problem is your service doen't have that property. Could you please check the service response from developer tool?

Comment: It would be great you can share the JSON response. So the things will be very easy for us :)

Comment: The first http call returns a word and an id of that word. I then send the word response from the first call as a param to the second call. The second response is where the 'text' property is.  

first response : `{id: 78671, word: "hourly"}
id: 78671
word: "hourly"
__proto__: Object`

Comment: I am talking about the second response , are you getting the response? Can u please share the response as a screenshot or data

Comment: **second response**

`[{…}]0: attributionText: "from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"citations: []exampleUses: []labels: []partOfSpeech: "adjective"relatedWords: []score: 0sequence: "0"sourceDictionary: "ahd-legacy"text: "Occurring every hour:  hourly chimes. "textProns: []word: "hourly"__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array(0)`

Comment: check my answer please..your response is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are getting the second response as a array. So you can access your text object like below if the array have always one object.

```
if(data){
     if(data.length>0)
        {
        this.defintion = data[0];
        console.log(this.defintion.text)
       }
}
```

Comment: I was able to get it that way, thank you!

Do i need `If(data[0]) ` though as the if check is only checking if the first response has been returned.

Comment: @Kasper better to check if(data){} // if you don't have response it will break. If your service guarantees the response have always one object you don't need data.length condition like in my answer

Comment: @Kasper Don't forget to mark it an answer and upvote if it;s answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

should be the same way as you are accessing the this.randomWord.word in your subscribe method.
Any object property can be accessed by using object.property.
In case of asynch calls though, make sure your object is available before accessing its properties. In your case, any property of the response object can be accessed in your subscribe method using response.property.

Comment: When i do `.subscribe((data: WordDefinition) => {
            this.defintion = data;
            console.log(this.defintion.text);
            })
` I am getting 'undefined'. Is this because the object is not available yet?

Comment: are you able to see data.text? If yes, then you know the problem is while assigning the value to the definition as objects are created by reference. make sure what types of objects are data and definition are.

Comment: `            console.log(this.defintion.text);
` This prints as undefined

Comment: what does  console.log(data.text) gives?